# Objective-C: I can't retrieve variable from another class's instance variable

Tags: objective-c

In my `WhatToEditViewController`, I created an `NSString` property called `whattoedit`. When the user presses a certain button, `whattoedit` gets assigned to a string.

```
@interface WhatToEditViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * whattoedit;

@end

#import "WhatToEditViewController.h"
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation WhatToEditViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)TappedMorning:(id)sender {
    self.whattoedit = @"Morning";
}

- (IBAction)TappedAfternoon:(id)sender {
    self.whattoedit = @"Afternoon";
}

- (IBAction)TappedEvening:(id)sender {
    self.whattoedit = @"Evening";
}
```

(I checked this part of my program works :/) Also when the user presses the button, a new view controller called `SettingsTableViewController` gets pushed in. What I want to do is set the title of the navigation bar of `SettingsTableViewController` as `WhatToEditViewController`'s `whattoedit` property.

Here is `SettingsTableViewController`'s implementation:

```
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"
#import "WhatToEditViewController.h"

@interface SettingsTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    WhatToEditViewController * editMode = [[WhatToEditViewController alloc] init];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = editMode.whattoedit;
}
```

Oddly, the navigation bar title turns into `(null)`. Should the `navigationBar.title` code be in the `viewDidLoad`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're initializing new `WhatToEditViewController` at viewDidLoad in your `SettingsTableViewController`, so the value of `whattoedit` becomes NULL

The correct way is to create a instance variable in your `SettingsTableViewController` that will update the value of title:

So, when you click the button to push in `SettingsTableViewController`, you should update the value like this:

**In your `SettingsTableViewController.h`:**

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *titleValue;

**In your `WhatToEditViewController`, when you push**

```
- (IBAction)pushToSettingVC:(id)sender {

SettingsTableViewController *setting = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsTableViewController"];
    setting.titleValue = YOUR_NEW_TITLE_VALUE_HERE;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:setting animated:YES];

}
```

**and in your `SettingsTableViewController.m` viewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    self.title = self.titleValue
}
```

Comment: it sort of worked. I had to alter some storyboard things. but all in all your tip  helped me achieve my goal. Tons of gratitude towards you sir! - the newb